# C# While loop until button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a program in Winforms (C#) in MS visual studio 2012

I need the code to do this

```
code code code
Event for button click from user
//Start while loop..
Do 
{
code code code
code code code
} (!button not click again)
```

I know that many talk about multithreading but I think that I am too low level to work with that for now, so if I can avoid it I will.

EDIT: I ended up using multithreading, thanks for all the answers it really helped me a lot, but at the time multithreading was hard to understand.

Comment: Multi-threading really isn't difficult when using a background worker. [Dot Net Pearls have a nice tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into pushing your work into a background thread. The reason for this is because the main UI thread is being stopped during the `while` loop which means the button won't be accessible to turn it off. (I know you said you want to avoid multiple threads but the reality is that you'll need to use them in this case).

The easiest way would probably be to use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). It will handle a lot of the thread spawning side of things for you. You can perform your `while` loop in the `DoWork` event handler of the background worker. This will free the UI thread which means the button will be clickable at which point you can set the flag to stop your loop.

Comment: Then i will try that out, i will accept you answer if i get it to work :-) else i will go back an ask you.

Tanks for the help.

Comment: Good luck :) If you can't get it to work, you'll get the best answers by showing what you've done so that we can try and help fix your code.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

The backgroundworker did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

The `Dispatcher` thread will be blocked by the `while` loop so it cannot handle messages which is why the application freezes. You can use the `BackgroundWorker` or the `Task` class to move the logic off the `Dispatcher`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // CancellationTokenSource will hold the CancellationToken struct
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // Task will hold the logic
    private readonly Task _task;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponents();

        // The task will be started on the ThreadPool off the Dispatcher thread
        _task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => EventLoop(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
    }

    private void EventLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while(!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Do work
        }

        // This exception will be handled by the Task
        // and will not cause the program to crash
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }

    private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
    }
}
```

See:

- [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx)
- [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you to look at threading, this is a summarily solution and i do not support this kind of programming, but for a beginner, it's a way to start.

```
code code code
Event for button click from user
//Start while loop..
Do 
{
code code code
code code code
    Application.DoEvents();
} (!button not click again)
```

Comment: You should not use Application.DoEvents.